# Partitioniing a sequence to minimize difference

Tags: c++, math

**Question:** We are given a sequence 1,2,3...N. We need to divide the given sequence into two parts A and B. We need to **minimize |a - b|** (where a is sum of elements in A, similarly b). To denote if it goes to A denote by "1" and if B denote by "0".

**Example:** For n = 3. The sequence will be 1,2,3 . Therefore (A:1,2) and (B:3), |a-b| = 0. The answer is **110**

**Problem:** I looked at mathematics and found if:

**(N is even):** answer would be of the form alternate **"01" --- "10"** upto size of **N**. Example **N = 6**, answer is: **"011001"**, the value |a-b| = 1.

**(N is odd):** answer would be of the form alternate **"00" --- "11"** upto size **N-1** and append **"0" if previous element is "1"** otherwise append "1". Example **N = 5**, answer is: **"00110"**, the value |a-b| = 1.

Did I miss any border case or my logic is incorrect because my answer is incorrect!

**Code:**

```
        if(n%2 == 0)
        {   
            ll count = n / 2;
            for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
            {
                 if(i%2 == 1)
                    cout << "01";
                        
                else
                    cout << "10";
            }
        }
        
        else
        {
            ll count = (n - 1) / 2;
                
            for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
            {
                if(i%2 == 1)
                    cout << "00";
                    
                else
                    cout << "11";
            }
            
            if(count%2 == 1)
                cout << "1";
                
            else
                cout << "0";
            
        }
        cout << endl;
```

Comment: Answer is incorrect for what input? How result should look? string? integer difference?

Comment: Don't know as this implementation has use in codechef problem. Answer should be a string

Comment: don't run the code only in codechef. Use your local compiler and debugger

Comment: Codechef link ?

Comment: Can't give this is implementation of ongoing challenge

Comment: Is there any error in logic?

Comment: I don't see errors. But perhaps site wants another answer format etc.

Comment: Are you expecting something more? Show exact problem definition and example of input-output ( codechef usually provides it)

Comment: Thanks I got it , exactly I was missing an output statement before this implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simpler code](https://ideone.com/hmjyMA) with the same result

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int odd = n % 2;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (((i + 1 - odd) % 4) / 2)
           cout << "1";
        else   
           cout << "0";
    }

    //bonus: difference
    cout << "\n" << (n + 1) % 4 / 2;
    return 0;
}
```